# Sine and cosine graph transformation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm having some difficulties with this question

A bike is on a stand such that the highest point of the back wheel is 47 inches above the ground. If the pedal is turned counter clockwise, the back wheel turns CCW also. The tire valve on the back wheel is 13 inches from the wheel's center of rotation.

now I need to define a function that gives the height of the tire valve

1) above the floor, if both the pedal and the tire valve start at 3 o'clock, and one revolution of the pedal results in one revolution of the tire valve.

2) above the tire's horizontal diameter, if the tire valve starts 3π/4 radians clockwise from 3 o'clock, and one revolution of the pedal results in one revolution of the tire.

3) above the floor, if both the pedal and the tire valve start at 3 o'clock, and 2 revolutions of the pedal results in 5 revolutions of the tire valve.

Comment: What is the independent variable in these functions? The number of rotations of the pedal, the angle the pedal is turned in degrees, the angle the pedal is turned in radians, or other? The first and the third are both mentioned in the questions.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are referring to a Cycloid as valve locus. R=13.

$$ x = R( \theta-\sin \theta) , y= R ( 1- \cos \theta). $$

Answer (score -1):

if the input is angle measure a, the number of radians swept by the pedal:

1) What I know so far: measured in inches, f(a)=13sin(a)+?
the floor to the tire bottom is 34" 
the floor to the horizontal diameter is 34"+13/2"
I am unsure if ? is 34 or 40.5

2) measured in radians, g(a)=sin(a-3pi/4)
This answer is confirmed by my math homework

3) my guess is that the argument is 5/2*a

Comment: 3) correction 13sin(5/2a)+34

Comment: 2) correction g(a)=sin(a-3pi/4)

Comment: 1) correction f(a)=13sin(a)+34